# R: Error in nrow[w] * ncol[w] : non-numeric argument to binary operator, while using neuralnet package

Tags: r, neural-network

I am using neuralnet package for training a classifier. 
The training data looks like this:

```
> head(train_data)
   mvar_12      mvar_40 v10       mvar_1   mvar_2  Labels
1 136.51551310       6   0   656.78784220      0      0
2 145.10739860      87   0    14.21413596      0      0
3 194.74940330       4   0   196.62888080      0      0
4 202.38663480       2   0   702.27307720      0      1
5  60.14319809       9   0    -1.00000000     -1      0
6  95.46539380       6   0   539.09479640      0      0
```

The code is as follows:

```
n <- names(train_data)
f <- as.formula(paste("Labels ~", paste(n[!n %in% "Labels"], collapse = " + ")))
library(neuralnet)
nn <- neuralnet(f, tr_nn, hidden = 4, threshold = 0.01,        
                stepmax = 1e+05, rep = 1, 
                lifesign.step = 1000,
                algorithm = "rprop+")
```

The problem arises when I try to make a prediction for a test set:

```
pred <- compute(nn, cv_data)
```

Where cv_data looks like:

```
> head(cv_data)
   mvar_12      mvar_40 v10      mvar_1    mvar_2
1 213.84248210       1   9  -1.000000000     -1
2 110.73985680       0   0  -1.000000000     -1
3 152.74463010      14   0 189.521812800     -1
4  64.91646778       7   0  47.854257730     -1
5 141.28878280      12   0 248.557857500      5
6  55.36992840       2   0   4.785425773     -1
```

To this I get an error saying:

```
Error in nrow[w] * ncol[w] : non-numeric argument to binary operator
In addition: Warning message:
In is.na(weights) : is.na() applied to non-(list or vector) of type 'NULL'
```

Why do I get this error and how can I fix it?

Comment: I have the same problem and so far havent found any indication what may cause it :(

Comment: does `nn <- neuralnet(f, tr_nn, hidden = 4, threshold = 0.01,  ...` produce warning about nn not converging within maxstep? I solved my problem by increasing stepmax (or threashold) untill it could converge to given threashold within maxstep. Only after that `compute` produced prediction.

Answer (score 4):

I just came up against the very same problem. Checking the source code of the `compute` function we can see that it assumes one of the resulting  attributes (i.e. `weights`) only defined when the network finishes the training flawless.

```
> trace("compute",edit=TRUE)
function (x, covariate, rep = 1) {
    nn <- x
    linear.output <- nn$linear.output
    weights <- nn$weights[[rep]]
    [...]
}
```

I think the real problem lies on the fact that `neuralnet` doesn't save the current network once reached the `stepmax` value, causing this error later in the `compute` code.

**Edit**

It seems you can avoid this reset by commenting lines *65* & *66* of the `calculate.neuralnet` function

```
> fixInNamespace("calculate.neuralnet", pos="package:neuralnet")
[...]
#if (reached.threshold > threshold) 
#    return(result = list(output.vector = NULL, weights = NULL))
[...]
```

Then everything works as a charm :)

Answer (score 3):

Try adjusting the `threshold` to a higher than 0.01 value or the  `stepmax` to more than 1e06, or using a `threshold` of 0.1 and then decreasing it from there. You can also add in the `lifesign = "full"` argument to observe the model creation performance in increments of 1000 steps to really dial in the threshold. This "resolved" the non-binary error I had, but the accuracy of the model, the mean squared error, and other results were less than satisfying as a direct result.

Comment: Wow I asked this question 4 years ago. I have moved on from R now (I still use it for data visualization but not serious machine learning). I don't think the neuralnet package in R is even comparable to what Tensorflow or PyTorch can do in Python.

Comment: @Adarsh Chavakula You're definitely right about Python usability versus  this particular package when it comes to deep learning. I typically use this one to feel out the model with the given data set and then go into more analysis/model construction with PyTorch.

Again, this helped me when I had the exact same error, but looking at the package documentation I now believe this error message is just a blanket message to cover several dissimilar situations.

Answer (score 0):

Do a str(cv_data) and make sure they are all numeric.

Comment: They are all numeric.

Answer (score -2):

Becasue you never set `startweights` in the function `neuralnet()` 
According to the documentation

```
neuralnet(formula, data, hidden = 1, threshold = 0.01,
    stepmax = 1e+05, rep = 1, startweights = NULL,
    learningrate.limit = NULL,
    learningrate.factor = list(minus = 0.5, plus = 1.2),
    learningrate=NULL, lifesign = "none",
    lifesign.step = 1000, algorithm = "rprop+",
    err.fct = "sse", act.fct = "logistic",
    linear.output = TRUE, exclude = NULL,
    constant.weights = NULL, likelihood = FALSE)

startweights            a vector containing starting values for the weights. The weights will not be randomly initialized.
```

Note that the default value is NULL, and it will NOT be randomly initialized. Try to put something there and see if that works.

Comment: Well it is not supposed to but I guess it DOES initialize with a random set of weights. I just discovered that this a problem with the convergence and depending on the choice of the random number seed the network may or may not converge. I don't get the mentioned error upon convergence.

Comment: If You dig trough a neuralnet function you will notice, that if startweight is set to NULL it will randomly assign weights on startup. Check function generate.startweights() in neuralnet package which is called by one of neuralnet subroutines when running neuralnet() training

Comment: The description for the argument 'startweights' `a vector containing starting values for the weights. The weights will not be randomly initialized` might be misleading. What is meant is that the startweights will not be randomly initialized *if and only if they are set by this parameter. If not set, they *will be randomly initialized.