# R: could not find function "generate.startweights", while using neuralnet package

Tags: r

I was running a neural network using the neuralnet package, but I ran into the problem where if the net hadn't achieved the threshold error predictions later would not work. I found the answer here: [R: Error in nrow[w] * ncol[w] : non-numeric argument to binary operator, while using neuralnet package](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26047901/r-error-in-nroww-ncolw-non-numeric-argument-to-binary-operator-while-u/35051097#35051097)

I opened the calculate.neuralnet function, as described in the answer, commented out lines 65 and 66, and saved it. Upon running the neuralnet again, I now get the error

```
Error in calculate.neuralnet(learningrate.limit = learningrate.limit, :could not find function "generate.startweights"
```

When I use the same fixInNamespace function to access the generate.startweights function, its there and accessible. I've since both reinstalled the package and uncommented those lines, but I still get the same error about generate.startweights, which I did not get before. I tried to comment on the original solution with my problems, but I do not have the requisite 50 reputation. Code below

```
regData <- read.csv('RegistrationandVoterData2.csv')
voteData <- read.csv('RegDataVote.csv')

mergeReg = regData[, 3:ncol(regData)]
mergeVote = voteData[, 6:ncol(voteData)]
mergeTotal = merge(mergeReg, mergeVote, by = c('RGPREC', 'RGPREC_KEY'), all = FALSE)
n<-names(mergeTotal[, c(3:66, 68:79)])
scaled <- scale(mergeTotal[, c(3:66, 68:79)])
scaleDF = as.data.frame(scaled)
names(scaleDF) = n
scaleDF$perDem = mergeTotal$DEM.y / (mergeTotal$REP.y + mergeTotal$DEM.y)
f <- as.formula(paste("perDem ~", paste(n[!n %in% "perDem"], collapse = " + ")))

smp_size <- floor(0.30 * nrow(mergeTotal))
## set the seed to make your partition reproductible
train_ind <- sample(seq_len(nrow(mergeTotal)), size = smp_size)

train <- scaleDF[train_ind, ]
smp_size2 = floor(0.2 *nrow(mergeTotal[-train_ind, ]))
test_ind = sample(seq_len(nrow(mergeTotal[-train_ind, ])), size = smp_size2)
test = scaleDF[-train_ind, ][test_ind, ]

errors = matrix(NA, 24, 2)
for(it in 2:25){
nn <- neuralnet(f,data=train,hidden=c(it),linear.output=T)
pr.nn <- compute(nn,test[, -ncol(test)])
preds = pr.nn$net.result
act = scaleDF$perDem[-train_ind][test_ind]
MSE.nn <- sum((act - preds)^2, na.rm = TRUE)/length(act)
pr.tr <- compute(nn,train[, -ncol(train)])
predsTr = pr.tr$net.result
actTr = scaleDF$perDem[train_ind]
MSE.nnTr <- sum((actTr - predsTr)^2, na.rm = TRUE)/length(actTr)
errors[it, ] = c(MSE.nnTr, MSE.nn)
}
```